# Position a Chart In the Center of the Page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, charts

does anyone know how can I position the chart at the **center** of the page? The chart always appear on the left of the page right now. My chart is created dynamically inside tab panel and I want my chart to be positioned at the center of the page.

This is my code:

```
//Aspx file
 <div>
             <asp:scriptmanager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:scriptmanager>
        </div>
        <asp:updatepanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ScrollBars="Horizontal">
            <contenttemplate>
        <asp:placeholder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:placeholder>

            </contenttemplate>
        </asp:updatepanel>

//Cs file
AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer container = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer();
            container.ID = "TabContainer";
            container.EnableViewState = false;
            container.Tabs.Clear();

foreach (ListItem item in SelectionListBox.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
            {
                Label tabContent = new Label();
                tabContent.ID = "lbl_tab_";
                tabContent.Text += item.Value;

Chart Chart1 = new Chart();
                        Chart1.DataSource = dt;
                        Chart1.Width = 715;
                        Chart1.Height = 450;

                        Chart1.Series.Add(new Series());
                        Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot;
                        List<object> List1 = dt_LVL1RISKCHART.AsEnumerable().ToList<object>();

                        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                            Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(row["STATUS"], new object[] { row["MIN"], row["MAX"], row["25TH_PERCENTILE"], row["75TH_PERCENTILE"], row["AVG"], row["50TH_PERCENTILE"] });

                        //create chartareas
                        ChartArea ca = new ChartArea();
                        ca .AxisX = new Axis();
                        ca .AxisY = new Axis();
                        Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(ca);

                        //databind
                        Chart1.DataBind();
                        Chart1.Visible = true;

                AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel panel = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel();
                panel.HeaderText += item.Value;
                container.Tabs.Add(panel);
                panel.Controls.Add(tabContent);
                panel.Controls.Add(Chart1);
            }
        }
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(container);
    }

    public AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel GetManualTab()
    {
        AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel panel = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel();
        return panel;
    }
```

Appreciate if anyone can help me on this, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Is there html that goes along with this?

Comment: There is no html, the chart is being created dynamically. The above coding shows how the chart is being created.

Comment: @Des is correct. There should be at least some container (div or panel) to which you will add dynamically created Chart control. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Take one div on ASPX (note the *align* attribute)

```
<div id="divChart" runat="server" align="center" />
```

Modify code behind to add this at the end (after data binding)

```
divChart.Controls.Add(Chart1);
```

This works as expected in FF and Chrome and IE.

Comment: hi @vnikhil, I could not use your method for this issue because my chart is created dynamically in a tab panel. I would like the chart to be located at the center of the tab panel. I have updated my codes, please take a look!

Comment: Shouldn't you have done this while posting question itself? That causes nothing but a confusion to *answerers* (slang). Also I formatted your code, then you updated it and lost formatting. So irritating, isn't it?